# Comparison of files of two folders according to their modified date

Tags: vb.net

I have two folders say A and B having exactly same no .of files with same name but different modified date and size. I want to compare each file of A to its respective file of folder B and get the newly modified file in a List box. If newly modified file belongs to folder A then it will come to ListBox1 and if its belongs to Folder B, then comes to listbox2.
I have started the code but m struck..!! can anyone of you help me?

```
Dim PathA As String= "" 'path for folder A
Dim PathB As String= "" 'path for folder B
Dim Dir1 As New System.Io.DirectoryInfo(PathA)
Dim Dir2 As New System.Io.DirectoryInfo(PathB)
Dim List1 = Dir1.GetFiles(*.*,System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Dim List2 = Dir2.GetFiles(*.*,System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Dim myFileCompare As New fileCompare
Dim areIdentical As Boolean = List1.sequence Equals (List2,myFileCompare)
```

What to do now???

Comment: You got some good answers last time you asked this question.  What part of what they suggested did you have trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

Need to implement a  FileInfoComparer and then call [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx) enumerable extension

```
Sub Main
    Dim PathA As String= "D:\temp" 'path for folder A
    Dim PathB As String= "D:\temp2" 'path for folder B
    Dim Dir1 As New System.Io.DirectoryInfo(PathA)
    Dim Dir2 As New System.Io.DirectoryInfo(PathB)
    Dim List1 = Dir1.GetFiles("*.*")
    Dim List2 = Dir2.GetFiles("*.*")

    Dim List3 = List1.Intersect(List2, new FileComparer)

    For Each info in List3
       Console.WriteLine(info.Name)
    Next

End Sub


Public Class FileComparer
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of FileInfo)

    Public Function Equals1(ByVal x As FileInfo, ByVal y As FileInfo) As Boolean _ 
                    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of FileInfo).Equals


        If x Is y Then Return True 
        If x Is Nothing OrElse y Is Nothing Then Return False 

        Return (x.Name = y.Name) AndAlso (x.Length = y.Length) AndAlso (x.LastWriteTime = y.LastWriteTime)
    End Function 

    Public Function GetHashCode1(ByVal info As FileInfo) As Integer _
                     Implements IEqualityComparer(Of FileInfo).GetHashCode

        If info Is Nothing Then Return 0
        Return info.Name.GetHashCode()
    End Function 
End Class
```